# Задержка звонков в asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip

Имеется `asterisk 16.1.1` `freepbx 14.0.1` При звонке между внутренними экстеншенами звонок проходит с задержкой в 15-20 с. При дебаге в консоли астериска выводится сообщение о невозможности создать канал в виду недоступности вызываемого абонента.

```
app_dial.c:2507 dial_exec_full: Unable to create channel of type 'SIP' (cause 20 - Subscriber absent)
```

Телефон зарегистрирован, о чем говорит строка в `sip show peers`. При снятии дампа видно, что на инвайт от вызывающего аппарата приходит ответ

```
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
```

Вот полный дамп:

```
14:55:49.453224 IP 192.168.1.111.sip > voip-main.ruan.local.sip: SIP
14:55:51.479421 IP 192.168.1.111.sip > voip-main.ruan.local.sip: SIP: INVITE sip:909@192.168.0.3:5060 SIP/2.0
14:55:51.479769 IP voip-main.ruan.local.sip > 192.168.1.111.sip: SIP: SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
14:55:51.485359 IP 192.168.1.111.sip > voip-main.ruan.local.sip: SIP: ACK sip:909@192.168.0.3:5060 SIP/2.0
14:55:51.492438 IP 192.168.1.111.sip > voip-main.ruan.local.sip: SIP: INVITE sip:909@192.168.0.3:5060 SIP/2.0
14:55:52.003257 IP 192.168.1.111.sip > voip-main.ruan.local.sip: SIP: INVITE sip:909@192.168.0.3:5060 SIP/2.0
14:55:53.023163 IP 192.168.1.111.sip > voip-main.ruan.local.sip: SIP: INVITE sip:909@192.168.0.3:5060 SIP/2.0
14:55:54.461031 ARP, Request who-has voip-main.ruan.local tell 192.168.1.111, length 46
14:55:54.461044 ARP, Reply voip-main.ruan.local is-at 00:50:56:98:4e:7e (oui Unknown), length 28
14:55:55.043010 IP 192.168.1.111.sip > voip-main.ruan.local.sip: SIP: INVITE sip:909@192.168.0.3:5060 SIP/2.0
14:55:56.611827 IP voip-main.ruan.local.sip > 192.168.1.111.sip: SIP: SIP/2.0 100 Trying
14:55:56.612860 IP voip-main.ruan.local.sip > 192.168.1.111.sip: SIP: SIP/2.0 100 Trying
14:55:56.613077 IP voip-main.ruan.local.sip > 192.168.1.111.sip: SIP: SIP/2.0 100 Trying
14:55:56.613349 IP voip-main.ruan.local.sip > 192.168.1.111.sip: SIP: SIP/2.0 100 Trying
14:55:56.710162 IP voip-main.ruan.local.sip > 192.168.1.111.sip: SIP: SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
14:55:56.751029 IP voip-main.ruan.local.sip > 192.168.1.111.sip: SIP: SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
14:56:03.679894 IP voip-main.ruan.local.sip > 192.168.1.111.sip: SIP: OPTIONS sip:991@192.168.1.111:5060 SIP/2.0
14:56:03.687937 IP 192.168.1.111.sip > voip-main.ruan.local.sip: SIP: SIP/2.0 200 OK
14:56:09.227421 IP 192.168.1.111.sip > voip-main.ruan.local.sip: SIP: CANCEL sip:909@192.168.0.3:5060 SIP/2.0
14:56:09.227665 IP voip-main.ruan.local.sip > 192.168.1.111.sip: SIP: SIP/2.0 487 Request Terminated
14:56:09.227708 IP voip-main.ruan.local.sip > 192.168.1.111.sip: SIP: SIP/2.0 200 OK
14:56:09.263295 IP 192.168.1.111.sip > voip-main.ruan.local.sip: SIP: ACK sip:909@192.168.0.3:5060 SIP/2.0
```

Не совсем понимаю в чем ошибка и почему asterisk не видит зарегистрированного телефона.

Comment: Кто есть кто? `192.168.1.111` - ip звонящего? `voip-main.ruan.local` - voip сервер? `192.168.0.3` - ip вызываемого аппарата?

Comment: @StuxForce 1.111 это трубка звонящего, 0.3 voip сервер (в данном случае астериск), voip-mail.ruan.local его хостнэйм. Вопрос решился командой `core restart now`. Но всё-же хочется понять суть проблемы.

Comment: `sip show peer <exten>` перед вызовом гляньте. Возможно, регистрация окончилась раньше чем ее продлил телефон. Или есть проблемы в сети, судя по нескольким INVITE без ответов.